# Dynamic source in Azure Data Factory copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

So I have a copy activity in an Azure Data Factory pipeline that copies data from 1 ODBC data source to Data Lake.

Now I have another ODBC source that I would like to do the same copy activity.

Is it possible to parameterize the source part in a copy activity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Please have a look at this doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc?tabs=data-factory#dataset-properties